# Show $P\left(A-B\right)=P\left(A\right)-P\left(A \cap B \right)$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to show that, given two events $A,B \in \Omega$ ($\Omega$ is a sample space):

$$P\left(A-B\right)=P\left(A\right)-P\left(A \cap B \right)$$

I know $A-B = A \cap B^C$, but I don't know how to use that to prove the given expression.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks! :)

P.S. Sorry if this question has already an answer here. I made a search *before* asking, but I couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw a Venn Diagram, you can find that $$A = (A\cap B) \cup (A - B).$$

By the axioms of probability of mututally exclusive events, we must also get $$P(A) = P((A\cap B) \cup (A - B)) = P(A\cap B) + P(A - B).$$

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Equivalently, we want to show that $\Pr(A\setminus B)+\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)$.

Note that $A\setminus B$ and $A\cap B$ are **disjoint** and have union equal to $A$. The result follows.

Comment: Your answer also helped me, I didn't realize I could do that! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. The "subtraction" version and the "addition" version" are algebraically equivalent. But the addition version is probably intuitively clearer.

Comment: And the best is the addition is an axiom!

Answer (score 1):

To think of it intuitively you can rewrite equation as $P(A\cap B^{c})+P(A\cap B)=P(A)$. Suppose you have an event A lets is when you get a good grade on your test and let event B be event that you studied. Well all this equation is saying that you can essentially "break up" the probability a good grade into probability you get good grade without studying and probability you get good grade with studying. These two probabilities should sum the whole probability that you get a good grade